# How can I make Tomboy notes link with both singular and plural forms?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, tomboy

Say I have a note named "apple". If I type "apples" in another note, it does not link. Is there a way to do one or all of the following?

- make plural forms link as well as singular
- give notes aliases
- as a last resort, manually link notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this in Tomboy itself, but somebody recently wrote an add-in that lets you manually set up redirects (like the alias idea you suggest).  I have not tried it yet:

http://lists.beatniksoftware.com/pipermail/tomboy-list-beatniksoftware.com/2009-July/001253.html

Answer (score 0):

These links help explain the situation:

- [Bug Report](http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=548078)
- [Mailing List Discussion](http://lists.beatniksoftware.com/htdig.cgi/tomboy-list-beatniksoftware.com/2007-April/000212.html)